CSS grid/flex shrink based on content but grow evenly
I am building a Navbar for my app. I would like to have my items shrink based on their content but grow based on the average size.
All I want is:

if there is enough space for all items to be max-content-size, I want the size to be even of all items.
if there is enough space for all items min-content, I want the items to shrink based on their content.
if there is not enough space for all items min-content, I want them to further shrink based on their content, so that the biggest item starts to shrink first, until it is as big as the secont biggest item, then both of them start to shrink


I could do this using grid or flex.
Unfortunately, I cannot get it the expected behavior as either they grow based on their content (and not based on the average size) or they shrink based on their average size and not based on their content. I included a snippet with two sample implementations.


body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.small {
  width: 400px;
}

.medium {
  width: 800px;
}

.large {
  width: 1200px;
}

.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-width: 0;
}

.title {
  background-color: white;
  flex-grow:0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 0;
}

.container-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-width: 0;
}
<div class="small">
<h2>Small</h2>
<h4>Flex</h4>
<div class="container-flex">
<div class="item-flex">
<div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-flex">
<div class="title">Long Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-flex">
<div class="title">Even longer Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-flex">
<div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
</div>
<h4>Grid</h4>
<div class="container-grid">
<div class="item-grid">
<div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-grid">
<div class="title">Long Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-grid">
<div class="title">Even longer Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-grid">
<div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="medium">
<h2>Medium</h2>
<h4>Flex</h4>
<div class="container-flex">
<div class="item-flex">
<div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-flex">
<div class="title">Long Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-flex">
<div class="title">Even longer Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-flex">
<div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
</div>
<h4>Grid</h4>
<div class="container-grid">
<div class="item-grid">
<div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-grid">
<div class="title">Long Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-grid">
<div class="title">Even longer Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-grid">
<div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="large">
<h2>Large</h2>
<h4>Flex</h4>
<div class="container-flex">
<div class="item-flex">
<div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-flex">
<div class="title">Long Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-flex">
<div class="title">Even longer Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-flex">
<div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
</div>
<h4>Grid</h4>
<div class="container-grid">
<div class="item-grid">
<div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-grid">
<div class="title">Long Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-grid">
<div class="title">Even longer Title</div>
</div>
<div class="item-grid">
<div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



The different sizes are just for testing, I am asking for a responsive solution working with different contents and different number of items.

The first two points you can achieve with grid-template-columns:repeat(4, minmax(min-content, 1fr)); but I can't figure out (yet!) the last point.

@Adam I tried, but all it does is overflowing it's parent. And in my actual implementation it doesn't have any effect. I also need to stick to auto-fill as the number of items can vary.

@Adam I further investigated and indeed this makes a difference. Though for me it would rather be grid-auto-columns: minmax(min-content, 1fr); (and remove grid-template-columns) instead to stick to the auto-fill like behavior.

I solved it in codepen, here's the link to the Codepen
Here is the HTML
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="" class="navbarLink">
    <div class="text">
      Title
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="navbarLink">
    <div class="text">
      Long Title
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="navbarLink">
    <div class="text">
      Even longer Title
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="navbarLink">
    <div class="text">
      Title
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

CSS
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  
  padding 10px
}

.navbar > a {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid green;

  font-size: 30px;
}

.navbar > a > .text {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1; /*Number of lines before an ellipsis... pops up */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}




Does the Job. Great! Decent job done! Instead of grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto; you could just use grid-auto-flow: column; to be a bit more generic.

@TimNikischin I've honestly never seen grid-auto-flow before, but thanks for letting me know thank you so much

with 3 different container behaviors, you need to change the characteristics for the cards.
"small container cards" need a max-width with overflow: hidden and text-overflow: ellipsis.
"medium container cards"  need a min-width and the default flex-shrink disabled.
"large container cards" need to preset the width to have all the equal width:


.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.container>* {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.5em rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.6);
  border: 1px dashed red;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 320px) 
  and (max-width: 524px) {
    .container > * {
      max-width: 5em;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
}

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 525px) 
  and (max-width: 719px) {
    .container > * {
      min-width: 3em;
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 720px) {
    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr));
    }
}
<div class="container">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div>Long Title</div>
  <div>Even longer Title</div>
  <div>Title</div>
</div>



The grid for larger screens does not care for the amount of child elements but will also not break by default. But without JS I don't see a solution that could do that.

Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question, but I am asking for a responsive solution and not fixed sizing. Also my items might have a different number or content.

for responsivness you just need to push the code into media queries instead of different classes

Sorry but this doesn't make sense or I get it wrong. If I don't know the number of items or the width of their content, how would I be able to set up media queries?

its a solution for responsivness not for the 2nd task. which you cant do without JavaScript. you can use flex-grow: 1 which will distribute the remaining space equally but not size all the elements equally. there might be a JS solution I have to check

Feel free to modify your example so it works as a generic solution without JS. But I don't yet understand how it would be different from the example I provided.
